# how to translate PHP code with serialization into a javascript code?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I got this line PHP code and I dont know how to translate it exactly in Javascript.

PHP code:

```
$data = ['username' => "myUsername", 'password' => "myPassword"];
serialize($data);
```

Is this the exact translated javascript code?
JS code:

```
let data = [{'username': "myUsername"}, {'password': "myPassword"}];
JSON.stringify(data);
```

original code is in PHP. so i need to modify the javascript in node.js

Comment: I believe you want this: `let data = {'username': "myUsername", 'password': "myPassword"};` using brackets `[]`, creates an array in javascript; using braces `{}`, creates an object.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` in javascript is a lot different from `serialize` in PHP. You could compare the outputs. However, if this is just for data transfer, then this will do just fine.

Comment: So even though the PHP code is an array. it will become a Javascript object if translated in javascript? also about the serialize is it same with JSON.stringify? Im not really familiar with PHP. but quite good in JS.

Comment: you will want [`json_encode($data)`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) with php

Comment: @vivek_23 this is for encryption of the request body that will be encrypted using AES. is there gonna be a problem? the working algo is using the PHP and i need to translate it in JS

Comment: hello @GetOffMyLawn the existing algo is in PHP and i need to translate it into JS

Comment: _“is there gonna be a problem?”_ - depends on what you actually want to do with the result afterwards … if who/whatever you are sending this to expects to have data in PHP’s serialize format again after decrypting it, then sending some other format such as JSON will likely _not_ do the trick.

Comment: you are right @misorude my API is in node.js and their API is in PHP code. Im going to encrypt the request body from my node api. then im gonna send it to their PHP api for decryption.. is there any work around?

Comment: @Makopa There is nothing in JavaScript that is similar to `serialize`

Comment: `serialize()` has nothing to do with JSON. That's a completely different serialization.

Comment: @Makopa You said you want to encrypt the request body. So how did PHP come into the picture?

Comment: thanks! that is very crucial. thats why im getting an error. maybe because serialize and JSON.stringify dont have same result when passed on AES encryption

Comment: @vivek_23 they sent me the algorithm for encryption but its in PHP code. so i need to translate it in javascript since my API is in node.js. however after my encryption in node im going to send the result/response to their API service for decryption which is in PHP

Comment: I would test the encryption (ja) and decryption (php) part early in your development. That can cause a few issues

Comment: **For your reference** The output from the PHP serialize code is `a:2:{s:8:"username";s:10:"myUsername";s:8:"password";s:10:"myPassword";}`

Comment: omg @RiggsFolly its weird looking format. thats maybe the reason why Im receiving an error. because I simply use JSON.stringify :(. they're service probably cant decrypt my request to their API

Comment: Its quite easy to read after you see a few. But it is definitely NOT JSON. And it is specific to PHP alone

Comment: Thats why I mentioned it, as the answer you have accepted does not in any way help you with your stated problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's almost good

to translate php array to js you have two solutions :

if it is a `key => value` array, it translate to an object

```php
$data = ['username' => "myUsername", 'password' => "myPassword"];
```

becomes

```js
let data = {'username': "myUsername", 'password': "myPassword"};
```

the `;` is optionnal and quotes `"`,`'` works as in php AFAIK

while `PHP` arrays without key translate to js array

```php
$data = ["myUsername", "myPassword"];
```

becomes

```js
let data = ["myUsername", "myPassword"]
```

these are similar

---

a way to know how to translate structure is to `json_encode` them in `php`, as `JSON` is a subset of `js` (not perfectly but these are edge case AFAIK), you can use the given JSON as your variable declaration in `js`

```js
// PHP :
// json_encode(['username' => "myUsername", 'password' => "myPassword"]);
// returns {"username":"myUsername","password":"myPassword"}

let myObject = {"username":"myUsername","password":"myPassword"}
console.log(myObject)

// same with non keyed array
// json_encode(["myUsername", "myPassword"]);
// returns ["myUsername","myPassword"]
let myArray = ["myUsername","myPassword"]
console.log(myArray)
```

---

here's a tentative to create [`serialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) in javascript

**[`Makopa`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8764701/makopa) gave [this node package which do the serialization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-serialize) in comments use it if you can as it will work better than this little script I made**

**Warning** it won't work exactly like serialize because :

- I can't find how to serialize callback functions because I couldn't get it to work so if someone has a working exemple I'm happy to add it
- JavaScript doesn't know anything about private/protected attribute in objects
- JavaScript doesn't make difference between int and double/float
- Any other situation I may have forgotten to test and thus didn't implement
- **If any of you find an error don't hesitate to tell me in comment**

```js
let serialize = value => {
  let serializeNull = value => {
    return `N;`
  }
  let serializeBool = value => {
    return `b:${value?1:0};`
  }
  let serializeInt = value => {
    return `i:${parseInt(value)};`
  }
  let serializeDouble = value => {
    return `d:${value};`
  }
  let serializeString = value => {
    return `s:${value.length}:"${value}";`
  }
  let serializeArray = value => {
    let serialized = `a:${value.length}:{`
    value.forEach((val, i) => {
      serialized += serialize(i)
      if(val === value) {
        throw new Error("sorry doesn't support array referencing themselves")
      } else {
        serialized += serialize(val)
      }
      
    })
    return serialized + "}"
  }
  let serializeKeyedArray = value => {
    let entries = Object.entries(value)
    let serialized = `a:${entries.length}:{`
    entries.forEach(entry => {
    
      serialized += serialize(entry[0])
      if(entry[1] === value) {
        throw new Error("sorry doesn't support array referencing themselves")
      } else {
        serialized += serialize(entry[1])
      }
      
    })
    return serialized + "}"
  }
  let serializeObject = value => {
    let entries = Object.entries(value)
    let serialized = `O:${value.constructor.name.length}:"${value.constructor.name}":${entries.length}:{`
    entries.forEach(([key, val]) => {
    
      serialized += serialize(key)
      // if protected key should become \0*\0${key}
      // if private key should become \0${value.constructor.name}\0${key}
      
      if(val === value) {
        serialized += "r:1;"
      } else {
        serialized += serialize(val)
      }
      
    })
    return serialized + "}"
  }
  
  switch(typeof value) {
    case "number": // int or double
      if (""+value == parseInt(""+value)) { return serializeInt(value) }
      else { return serializeDouble(value) }
      break
    case "boolean": // boolean
      return serializeBool(value) 
      break
    case "string": // string
      return serializeString(value)
      break
    case "undefined": // undefined
      return serializeNull(value)
      break
    case "object": // Array, primitive object, object from class or null
      if (Array.isArray(value)) { return serializeArray(value) }
      else if (value === null) { return serializeNull(value) }
      else if (value.constructor.name !== "Object") { return serializeObject(value) }
      else { return serializeKeyedArray(value) }
      break
    default: throw new Error("sorry I don't know how to serialize this")
  }
}

class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    this.self = this
    this.a = 42
    this.b = "How are you ?"
  }
}

let tests = [
  {expected: `i:1;`, val: 1},
  {expected: `i:-1;`, val: -1},
  
  {expected: `d:1;`, val: 1.0},
  {expected: `d:1.5;`, val: 1.5},
  {expected: `d:-4.2;`, val: -4.2},
  
  {expected: `b:1;`, val: true},
  {expected: `b:0;`, val: false},
  
  {expected: `N;`, val: null},
  {expected: `N;`, val: undefined},
  
  {expected: `s:4:"test";`, val: "test"},
  {expected: `s:5:"hello";`, val: "hello"},
  
  {expected: `a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;s:2:"hi";i:2;i:5;}`, val: [1, "hi", 5]},
  
  {expected: `a:3:{s:1:"a";i:1;s:1:"b";s:2:"hi";s:1:"c";i:5;}`, val: {a:1, b:"hi", c:5}},
  
  {expected: `O:9:"TestClass":3:{s:4:"self";r:1;s:1:"a";i:42;s:1:"b";s:13:"How are you ?";}`, val: new TestClass()}
]

tests.forEach(val => {
  let serialized = serialize(val.val)
  let log = `expected : '${val.expected}', got : '${serialized}', value : ${(()=>{
    if(typeof val.val === "object") {
      return val.val ? Object.entries(val.val).join(", ") : val.val // null
    } else {
      return val.val ? val.val.toString() : val.val // undefined
    }
  })()}`
  if(val.expected === serialized) {
    console.log(log)
  } else {
    console.error(log)
  }
})
```

There are still errors as you can see :

- the `double` having no usefull digit after the dot (like `1.0000`) are considered `int` because in JS they are both the same `Number`

*return values are based on the return of `serialize` on [this site](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) running php `7.3.5` on the 7th and 8th of august 2019*

Comment: Except this ignored the use of `serialize()` for which there is no javascript equivalent

Comment: Yes...was not going to mention this but .....  "IDK serialize yet" does not really belong in an answer to a question that has `serialize()` as a major part of it

Comment: thanks everyone for the concern. I guess ill just use node package to handle the serialization in node.js

Comment: @Makopa Is this new code, or are you redeveloping an existing API

Comment: @RiggsFolly hi! well. my client service is in PHP code. so they send me how to encrypt the request body then send it to their PHP service. the algo they sent to me is in PHP code. However my API is built from node.js. so Im gonna write the algorithm in in javascript then send the response to their PHP service for decryption.

Comment: See [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396757/how-to-translate-php-code-with-serialization-into-a-javascript-code#comment101276043_57396757) about how that `serialize()` output looks

Comment: If the client absolutely HAS TO HAVE the data in a  `serialise()` format as they are expecting to do an `unserialise()` on it. You are gona have a major hassle doing that in JS

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just got home and looked a little into serialise, I should be able to recreate serialise or at least what I understand of it in the next hour

Comment: you are right @RiggsFolly they are already in production and supporting many clients. so i cant request to change their code. I need to adjust on my end. btw I found this node package that might solve the problem https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-serialize thanks for your inputs!